# Database how to model Investment Relationship

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I am trying to model relationships between investment vehicles to view links between entities and roll up transaction data. I have started with two tables:

**tblInvestmentVehicle** (one)

VehicleID (PK)
VehicleName
Type

**tblVehicleRelationships** (many)

VehicleRelationID (PK)
InvestingVehicleFrID
InvesteeVehicleFrID
Units
Type

This works fine for basic relationships e.g. V 1 invests in V 10 and has 100 units.

The complication is that I now need to model a situation where multiple vehicles invest in another vehicle via a holding vehicle, e.g. V 1,2,3 invest in V10 via V4.

I have tried to research the best approach but am struggling with the correct terminology to find relevant results hence seeking advice here.

My approach so far has been to create another table that links relationships together:

**tblVehicleSubRelationships**

ParentVehicleRelationID
ChildVehicleRelationID
Units
Type

This seems to be a step in the right direction but I am now struggling to make the final step to produce meaningful output e.g. show all investments from a top level vehicle or all investments of a particular vehicle type.

Would appreciate any suggestions from anyone who may have already modelled something similar or has ideas on a good approach. Probably something relatively simple but I am at a mental road block..

Comment: Why not add *HoldingVehicleFrID* in the second table? And leave it NULL if not applicable.

Comment: MS Access!? Is this for real or just homework?

Comment: @Parfait - I will give the HoldingVehicleFrID a try, might just work - thanks!

Comment: It is an old MS Access project that is being re-built on SQL / Azure. Access might still form part of the front end until a web UI can be developed.

Answer (score 1):

If your data concerns regulated financial products and markets then there are official and de facto data standards that you ought to be aware of. Consider reusing their definitions and structures wherever possible rather than inventing your own. There is a useful list of some standards on this page: http://xml.coverpages.org/mddl.html#relatedSpecs

If you are in Europe then adherence to MiFID II is mandatory for anyone buying and selling investments. Regulated organizations invariably have their own data standards as well.

Comment: Thats a useful resource - thanks. Its only a small internal system within a small co so no data will be exchanged with other parties but does make sense to follow the de facto standards where possible.